# Sitecore sitecore Factory.GetDatabase vs Sitecore.Data.Database.GetDatabase

Tags: sitecore

Can anyone tell me the difference between:

```cs
Sitecore.Data.Database.GetDatabase("master")
```

and

```cs
Factory.GetDatabase("master")
```

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference.

`Sitecore.Data.Database.GetDatabase` calls `Factory.GetDatabase` internally anyway:

```cs
public static Database GetDatabase(string databaseName)
{
  Assert.ArgumentNotNullOrEmpty(databaseName, "databaseName");
  return Factory.GetDatabase(databaseName);
}
```